# Formula/Function to determine if all cells are the same but ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, google-sheets

*Basically, I want to indicate "TRUE" in K2 when all the cells in E2:J2 are "YES", not "NO" and ignoring blanks.*

I'm not sure if I am in the right place, but I've been on this site before to look for answers.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14U1LpZ-C0vqNLFh6BwOdgYMCKfqIJpmH_AhrC1m4114/edit?usp=sharing

So in E2:J2, it should come out as "FALSE" because there is a "NO"

In E3:J3, it should come out as "TRUE" because they are all "YES" and the blanks are ignored

In E4:J4, it should come out as "FALSE" because all of the blanks were ignored.

The closest I came was **=IF(COUNTIFS(E2:J2,">""",E2:J2,"NO")=0,,(COUNTIFS(E2:J2,">""",E2:J2,"NO")))**

The problem with that function is that set it so that all blanks were treated as zero. So in the table below, K would have read "TRUE" if they were all blanks.

I'm not exactly proficient at this and everything I've done to this point has been self-taught through Googling what other people have done. I'm sure there is a simple way and I am making this way more complex than necessary. But I can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most attractive formula but it works.

```
=IF(OR(E2 <> "",F2 <> "",G2 <> "",H2 <> "",I2 <> "",J2 <> ""),IF(AND(OR(E2 = "Yes",E2 = ""),OR(F2 = "Yes",F2 = ""),OR(G2 = "Yes",G2 = ""),OR(H2 = "Yes",H2 = ""),OR(I2 = "Yes",I2 = ""),OR(J2 = "Yes",J2 = "")),"TRUE","FALSE"),"FALSE")
```

**EDIT** - A much better formula suggested by someone on the product forms.

```
=ISODD((COUNTIF(E2:J2,"YES")>0)*(COUNTIF(E2:J2,"NO")=0))
```

Comment: That's great! Someone on the Google forums found a way that I never would have sorted out: =ISODD((COUNTIF(E2:J2,"YES")>0)*(COUNTIF(E2:J2,"NO")=0))

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I knew there would be an easier way but I would have never thought of that!!